# How do I change numeric data that is reading in as a character in R?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I am trying to read in a csv file (exported from survey monkey). 
I have tried `survey <- read.csv("Survey Item Evaluation2.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`
I ran `skim(survey)`, which shows it is reading in as characters.

`str(survey)` output: data.frame: 623obs. of 68 variables. G1 (which is a survey item) reads in as chr "1" "3" "4" "1"....

How do I change those survey item variables to numeric?

Comment: Use `as.numeric` `survey[] <- lapply(survey, as.numeric)` there would be some warning, if there are charracter elements that gets changed to NA

Comment: If you want to change only `G1` to numeric use `survey$G1 <- as.numeric(survey$G1)`

Comment: Thank you! I had tried this and it completely messed it up. Yours worked though! survey<-as.numeric(unlist(survey))
survey<-lapply(survey, as.numeric)

Comment: Be careful if you think the columns should be numeric and they are imported as characters. Do a quick tabulation using `table` to check why this may be the case. Often online surveys don't have any quality control mechanisms. Participants may have entered garbage accidentally, which may need careful  data management if you don't want to lose these data.

Comment: Your question really should be: "WHY am I getting character data when I'm sure this variable should be numeric?". To which the answer would be: "Either your not reading the data correctly (does the data start at row 3), or there is non-numeric (garbage) data among the numeric data (for example NA is entered as `.` or some other character), or certain people entered a `,` instead of a `.` to represent decimal point (such as nationals of Indonesia and some Europen countries), or some other unknown reason which needs further investigation".

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to your question is given in the first two comments by two very well respected people with a combined reputation of over 600k. I'll post their very similar answer here:

```
as.numeric(survey$G1)
```

However, that is not very good advice in my opinion. Your question should really have been:

## "Why am I getting character data when I'm sure this variable should be numeric?"

To which the answer would be: "Either your not reading the data correctly (does the data start at row 3), or there is non-numeric (garbage) data among the numeric data (for example `NA` is entered as `.` or some other character), or certain people entered a `,` instead of a `.` to represent decimal point (such as nationals of Indonesia and some European countries), or they entered a thin thousand separator instead of a comma, or some other unknown reason which needs further investigation. Maybe a certain group of people enter text instead of numbers for their age (`fifty` instead of `50`), or they put a `.` at the end of the data, for example `62.5.` instead of `62.5` for their age (older folks were taught to always end a sentence with a period!). In these last two cases, certain groups (elderly) will have missing data and your data is then missing not at random (MNAR), a big bias in your analysis".

I see this all too often and I worry that new users of R are making terrible mistakes due being given poor advice, or because they didn't learn the basics. Importing data is the first step of analysis. It can be difficult because data files come in all shapes and sizes - there is no global standard. Data is also often entered without any quality control mechanisms. I'm glad that you added the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` argument in your command to import the data. Someone gave you good advice there. But that person forgot to advise you not to trust your data, especially if it was given to you by someone else to analyse. Always check every variable carefully before the analysis. This can take time, but it can be worth the investment.

Hope that helps at least someone out there.